# Field-based hyperlinks in an ArcMap map package (.mpk)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, hyperlink, photos, map-package

I have a point shapefile where each point has multiple hyperlink fields in its attribute table as per [How to add multiple relative hyperlinks to single point in ArcGIS for Desktop with Basic level license?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54555/adding-multiple-relative-hyperlinks-to-a-single-point-feature-class-in-arcmap) These hyperlinks are to photos stored locally.

Ideally I want to bundle up the map (shapefiles and all) and the photos and export them as a map package (*.mpk) so that the receiver can open it up and click on the hyperlinks in the shapefiles.

Is there any way of doing this? I know the map package export function has the option to include additional files but I am not sure how to get this to work for me.
Attachments are not an option, as my licence is Basic, and geodatabases or dynamic hyperlinks are not options as I need each point feature to link to multiple photos.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to include the photos as additional files when creating the map package, and setting the hyperlinks to the anticipated relative path (here it was *..\commondata\userdata*, as discussed in the ArcMap help on laying out relative hyperlinks) in the extracted *.mpk folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to provide a slight variation to @Willis answer. They suggested a solution which requires storing your photos in the anticipated folder location of a map package.

Whilst this appears to be the only solution I don't like it as ..\commondata\userdata is not a folder structure used by my organization. I wonder if *anyone* actually uses these folder names?

So I have a point featureclass with links to photos:
[image: Attribute Table]

For the layer property I set it to the name field as shown below:

[image: Layer property]

Normally I would have the hyper link field as **Path**. But just before I attempt to create the map package I go into the document properties and set the hyperlink base (this would normally be blank) to the map package location as shown below:

[image: Map document properties]

Open the map package and the hyper-links function as expected.